# Is there a way to find which libraries are using DTV slots for a given process?

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, dlopen

For a given process I want to find which libraries are occupying DTV slots. If my understanding is correct if a library uses initial-exec model, then it would need a DTV slot. I would like to find all the libraries that are loaded for a process that use initial-exec model.

Comment: Not sure if this is a reliable way (or most convenient), but I followed what was the advice in https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1124987. Which is basically to parse strace to find all the libraries used in the process, then on each library execute a readelf -a -W finally search for symbols that use TLC.

Comment: Could you create an aswer based on #1124987 so that we can +1 it?